# How To Override Custom Module Helper in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides

I would need to override the custom module helper into my custom module.

Custom module code was,

```
class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    const XML_PATH_BLOG = 'blog/';
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $objectManager;
    protected $postfactory;
    protected $categoryfactory;
    protected $tagfactory;
    protected $topicfactory;
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        PostFactory $postFactory,
        CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        TagFactory $tagFactory,
        TopicFactory $topicFactory,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    )
    {
        $this->objectManager   = $objectManager;
        $this->storeManager    = $storeManager;
        $this->postfactory     = $postFactory;
        $this->categoryfactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->tagfactory      = $tagFactory;
        $this->topicfactory    = $topicFactory;
        $this->scopeConfig     = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

My overriding code was,

```
class Resize extends \Mageplaza\Blog\Helper\Data
{
    protected $_filesystem;
    protected $_directory;
    protected $_imageFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_storeManager   = $storeManager;
        $this->_filesystem     = $filesystem;
        $this->_imageFactory   = $imageFactory;
        $this->_directory      = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    }
```

Am I missed anything here? Because, it throws the following error when I was calling the method called `getConfigValue()` as follow:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getValue() on null in E:\xxxamp\htdocs\accelerator\app\code\Mageplaza\Blog\Helper\Data.php on line 50

```
public function getConfigValue($field, $storeId = null)
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue($field, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor in the `Resize` class should look like this:

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    PostFactory $postFactory,
    CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    TagFactory $tagFactory,
    TopicFactory $topicFactory,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory
)
{
    $this->_filesystem     = $filesystem;
    $this->_imageFactory   = $imageFactory;
    $this->_directory      = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    parent::__construct($context, $objectManager, $storeManager, $postFactory, $categoryFactory, $tagFactory, $topicFactory, $scopeConfig);
}
```

Comment: Yes it is correct. I didn't get any error now.

Comment: Marius, can you please tell me why should we pass the objects in __contruct(???). Because, In some cases we are not passing those objects.

Comment: this is how Dependency Injection works in M2. You have to supply in the class constructor all the dependencies it needs. And Magento will take care of instantiating them.